# How to check for and discard invalid multi-line JSON log requests in log files?

Tags: python, json

I'm writing a script to parse some of our requests, and I need to be able to handle when we have a malformed or incomplete requests.  So for example, a typical request would come in with the following format:

`log-prefix: {JSON request data}\n`

all on a single line, etc...

Then I found out that they have a character buffer limit of 1024 in their writer, so the requests could be spread across many lines, like so:

`log-prefix: {First line of data
log-prefix: Second line of requests data
log-prefix: Final line of log data}\n`

I'm able to handle this by just calling next on the iterator I'm using, and then removing the prefix, concatenating the requests, and then passing it to `json.loads` to return my `dictionary` that I need for writing to a file.

I'm doing that in the following way:

```
lines = (line.strip('\n') for line in inf.readlines())
for line in lines:
    if not line.endswith('}'):
        bad_lines = [line]
        while not line.endswith('}'):
            line = next(lines)
            bad_lines.append(line)
            form_line = malformed_data_handler(bad_lines)
        else:
            form_line = parse_out_json(line)
```

And my functions used in the above code are:

```
def malformed_data_handler(lines: Sequence) -> dict:
    """
    Takes n malformed lines of bridge log data (where the JSON response has
    been split across n lines, all containing prefixes) and correctly
    delegates the parsing to parse_out_json before returning the concatenated
    result as a dictionary.

    :param lines: An iterable with malformed lines as the elements
    :return: A dictionary ready for writing.
    """
    logger.debug('Handling malformed data.')
    parsed = ''
    logger.debug(lines)
    print(lines)
    for line in lines:
        logger.info('{}'.format(line))
        parsed += parse_out_malformed(line)
    logger.debug(parsed)
    return json.loads(parsed, encoding='utf8')


def parse_out_json(line: str) -> dict:
    """
    Parses out the JSON response returned from the Apache Bridge logs.  Takes a
    line and removes the prefix, returning a dictionary.

    :param line:
    :return:
    """
    data = slice(line.find('{'), None)
    return json.loads(line[data], encoding='utf8')


def parse_out_malformed(line: str) -> str:
    prefix = 'bridge-rails: '
    data = slice(line.find(prefix), None)
    parsed = line[data].replace(prefix, '')
    return parsed
```

So now to my problem, I've now found instances where the log data can look like this:

`log-prefix: {First line of data
....
log-prefix: Last line of data (No closing brace)
log-prefix: {New request}`

My first though to handle this was to add some sort of check to see if `'{' in line`.  Since I'm using a generator for scalability to process the lines, I don't know that I have found one of these requests until I have already called next and pulled the line out of the line generator, and at that point I can't re-append it, and I'm not sure how to efficiently tell my process to then start from that line and continue normally.

Comment: Why don't you try using `json.loads`, catch a `ValueError` (can't parse it), add the line to a list, and the next line you read concatenate it with everything in that list and try `json.loads` again until you don't get a `ValueError`? Is there likely to be non-JSON sprinkled in that will break this? (Other than `....` which you can easily filter out)

Comment: No non-JSON, I thought about this approach.  Would it be super expensive computationally to try to call `json.loads` on it repeatedly?

Comment: No more expensive than if every line were JSON and there weren't any broken up...